# FFMPEG - Extract color-accurate image sequence from UHD MOV in bt.2020

Tags: image-processing, video, ffmpeg, hdr

Im trying to use FFMPEG to extract an image sequence from an MOV that comes from an iphone 13 with bt2020

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-10-11T16:12:07.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 15.0.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-10-11T18:12:07+0200
  Duration: 00:00:07.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8693 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 8472 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
```

But i haven't been able to get a color match on any extracted images. I have tried following a number of posts, a few on jpgs (most said it would have to be a PNG) and a few on PNG. But no matter what I seem to try, i end up with a lifted, less saturated image. I can only use jpg or PNG in this case - am I just stuck with a non-accurate color image extraction on HDR, or is there something I am missing here?

I have tried playing with scale and colormatrix commands, trying different options to go from bt2020:bt709 (though im not sure this is the correct approach, or if I mis-formatted something). I also tried a suggestion on another post to get 10bit PNG out - but ended up with the exact same color issue as just extracting a standard jpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i img_2106.mov -vsync 0 -f image2 test.%04d.png
```

and many other variations of options.

Anyone have any suggestions?

as added info im using:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
```

Comment: Only AVIF supports this properly. But patches for ffmpeg for AVIF is work in progress.